How do I automate code signing in VS Code?
How do I automate code signing in Visual Studio Code ? I have a personal certificate and I need to sign every created EXE (C#) in VS Code. I know, there is some signtool.exe, but how to create pre/post build task in VS Code ?
Maybe in *.csproj should I add something ?
csproj file
Thank you.

Don't link .csproj. Add its contents as formatted text.

On topic: I think you want a Build Event

@gunr2171 is there a better dupe? That one merely matches based on title. Nothing in it would help the OP or anyone having that problem.

OP is confused between making a task in VS Code and making a build event in the csrpoj file. The link shows how to do the latter, which we both agree is what they want.

Hi, it does not help me. I think I need to create some tasks.json.

I have created tasks.json in c:\Users...\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\ with signtool tasks. Then I have created folder .vscode in project folder with launch.json file, where I define preLaunchTask. It is not perfect, but it is running.
